# Выбор технологии для кросс-платформенного сайта

Tags: php, javascript, android, ios, angular

Раньше было проще выбрать технологии для веб проекта, сервер пишешь на php, фронтенд на `html + js`, все сам, никаких проблем. Но со временем технологии начали появляться одна за другой, и я понял, что очень сильно отстал.

Планирую разработку Web портала, чтобы пользоваться им было удобно как с ПК, так и с мобильных устройств, а также была возможность скачать приложение через App Store или Google Play. Сервер собираюсь писать на php, знаю фреймворк Yii2.

В клиенте использовать `bootstrap`. С js фреймоворками голова кругом, есть и angular, и react, и vue. На одном сайте написано, что angular рулит, а react кошмар, на другом пишут наоборот и тп. Я как понял эти фреймворки подходят больше для лендинг-сайтов, визиток и тп, в общем одностраничных, полноценно на них портал не построишь, где-то местами его можно использовать. Посмотрел технологии, которые преобразовывают сайт в приложение для телефонов (ionic,react native).

На портале js планирую использовать для модальных окон, работ с формами, вывода графиков, подгрузки некоторой информации без перезагрузки страницы.

Как посоветуете написать сервер в данном случае, чтобы можно было без проблем работать в будущем с приложением для мобильных устройств? Api? Какие технологии использовать? `Yii2 + bootstrap + jQuery`? `Yii2 + bootstrap + (angular/react)` и тп? А в дальнейшем писать клиент на телефон и манипулировать данными с сервера через Api Yii2?

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Скажу, пожалуй, только то, что считать что Angular или Vue подходят только для одностраничников - это преступно, изучите их лучше. А жиквери, кто бы что не говорил, пережиток прошлого.

Comment: Вы будете удивлены, но и пхп уже тоже не в моде. А фреймверки как раз наоборот ближе к большим сайтам. jquery очень практичен в лендингах, и небольших сайтах.

Comment: @l2banners  а обоснованность вашего выражения по поводу php какая ?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что две трети перечисленных здесь названий не нужны, но хипстота со мной не согласится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем и целом не важно на чём всё писать, если писать правильно.

Можно сделать как-то так:

1. Сервер на чём угодно. Он должен предоставлять API для всех нужных запросов извне.
2. Фронтенд на чём угодно. Он должен дёргать API сервера и выводить данные/позволять отправлять данные на сервер через его API
3. Приложение на чём угодно, оно должно работать также как фронт - запрашивать данные из API и отправлять их через него же.

За все технологии не отвечу, опишу что пробовал:

1. Сервер на Spring+Kotlin+Postgresql - очень круто.
2. Фронт на Angular - очень круто.
3. Андроид на Java/Kotlin - очень круто.

А все фреймворки друг от друга в основном нюансами отличаются, т.е. можно на любом пилить. А под андроид/яблоко лучше нативно, если хочется сделать красиво и неглючно.

Comment: Типа аминь (хотя Angular я бы заменил на Vue, первый - это костыль, пытающийся JS превратить в Java). Только почему Вы не закрыли вопрос, слишком общий же.

Comment: @Other, да, про Vue слышал, но <s>по желанию левой пятки</s> решил взять гугловое решение, т.к. в основном под андроид пишу и привык к гуглу. То что на Java похоже - в моём случае плюс скорее) А вопрос не закрыл, т.к. он мне интересным показался, на него можно что-то вразумительное ответить не скатившись во вкусовщину + он и так почти закрыт и злоупотреблять своей закрывательной способностью я не хочу)

Comment: Как мне кажется, делать из достаточно значимого языка (кто бы что не говорил, а JS сильно повлиял на веб (и он крут ИМХО!)) копию другого языка, пусть тоже значимого... Идея так себе.

Comment: @Other, ну... Я больше обратил внимание не собственно на язык, а на то, что как и в Android тут инъекции зависимостей, навигация и компоненты имеют прямые аналоги в андроиде. Т.е. мне было очень удобно и понятно что и как сделать после беглого просмотра примеров. А синтаксис конкретного используемого языка, в общем, как по мне, не так важен.

Comment: Вывод: Angular сделали для безболезненного перехода с андроида :)

Comment: @Other, не во всём) Та же навигация, аналог которой есть в андроиде только в виде сторонней либы, которая не является в данный момент общепринятым стандартом, т.е. не факт, что гугл про неё в курсе. Но да, общие подходы видны)

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что на сервере можно API сделать и отдавать данные под клиент для андойда на Java?

Comment: Да. У вас и фронт и андроид и иОС будут просто клиентскими приложениями для API и дергать одни и те же методы одними и теми же способами

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли разобраться!
Успехов Вам.